# Mimicking the behavior of 'git commit --fixup' in Cygwin (Git 1.7.3.3)

Tags: git

I want to use the new `git commit --fixup` feature. Unfortunately, it was added in git 1.7.4 and I'm on cygwin which is using git 1.7.3.3 so it's unavailable. It seems like it should be easy enough to mimic the behavior though. Let's say I want to make a small change which really should have been included in the commit that is currently at `HEAD~2`. So I want to do:

```
$ git commit -m "fixup! `git show --format=%s HEAD~2`"
$ git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

but `git show` with those options prints out the entire diff when all I want is the commit message itself. What is the git command to print *just* the commit message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually shown on the [git show](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html) documentation page as an example, but it's not explained:

```
$ git commit -m "fixup! `git show -s --format=%s HEAD~2`"
```

The `-s` is described on the [git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) page, under "Diff Formatting". It means "suppress diff output". It was not immediately obvious to me that options listed under `git log` would also be valid for `git show`.

Comment: This is a sort of known documentation issue, apparently. It's been undocumented forever, and then was fairly recently added to the log manpage in commit [60aa9cf8f370b69eb7feaad2e1cbcd04280bc799](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=60aa9cf8f370b69eb7feaad2e1cbcd04280bc799)

Comment: You can also use `git log -n 1 <format> <commit>`, or even `git log -1 ...`. At least the first one of those is well-documented.